# Imagepiker without chooser dialog

Tags: android, image

I call the imagepicker like that:

```
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputX", Config.image_size/2);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputY", Config.image_size/2);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, getTempUri());
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG.toString());
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE);
```

But I don't want that show the chooser dialog, I want use the default android gallery App.

Can Anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: "I call the imagepicker like that" -- few "imagepicker" implementations will pay any attention to those extras. There are [many image cropping libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/45). Please use one. "I want use the default android gallery App" -- there is no one "default android gallery App". There are ~1 billion actively used Android devices, covering thousands of device models from hundreds of manufacturers.

Comment: I mean this gallery:   http://www.androidpolice.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/nexusae0_2012-10-12-01old.jpg

Comment: Some devices have that app. Manu devices instead have other "gallery" apps, set up by their device manufacturers.

Comment: The point is, can I put a default App and if it is not in the device, show the chooser?